# Only show menu level 2 from active trail (with option Show as expanded)

Tags: routes, 8

I'm trying to do something pretty basic in my perspective, but I keep failing at this simple task.

My website has a main menu that is displayed on top of the page that is 2 levels deep (hence the Show as expanded). On the left toolbar it has another display of main menu, starting from `level 2`.

I have a main menu that looks like the following:

```
-link 1 (has option show as expanded)
--link 1.1
--link 1.2
-link 2 (has option show as expanded)
--link 2.1
--link 2.2
```

Problem now is that in the left toolbar all my level 2 links are always displayed, probably because I expand them. But I only want to view the children from my active trail.

Is this possible at all with the current setup? When I deselect Show as expanded, my top menu doesn't show the second level (except when I click the first level `first = active` trail).

Another problem with this new (menu) block system is that I use a template to render my main menu: `menu--main.html.twig` but both my top and left menu use this template. Is there any best practice to separate the templates?

Comment: Have you tried the [Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module?

Comment: It's D8, so doesn't have menu block

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Then I have no idea :) I suppose some contrib work similar to menu_block or menupoly needs to happen in D8 then.

Comment: D8 enables you to add custom blocks (of type Menu or type View) already. So menu_block seems useless, although I was able to do my functionality with menu_blocks without any problems.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to separate the templates for your menus?? I have the same issue. I want to have a different template for level 2 of the main menu. I was hoping I could expose the block id in the menu preprocess function and then use it in my main menu twig file, but I've been unsucessful. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this??

Answer (score 1):

I also discovered that if "Show as expanded" is checked, the menu is displayed at sublevels where it should not appear. This patch fix this behavior:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2631468#comment-10792980