# Main menu level 2 template

Tags: blocks, theming, navigation

I have my main navigation menu setup with 2 levels with only one level expanded by default. I then placed a second version of the menu in a different block and set the Initial Menu Level to 2 so on this one I only see the second level menu. It's working as I want it but I've run into an issue trying to style it. The problem is that both menu levels are using the same template so there's no way for me to differentiate them. I can change the wrapping block template, but I also need to be able to edit the menu template for each level.

I was hoping I could use a preprocess function to pass the block id of where the menu is placed so then I could use some logic on the menu template. However since I'm fairly new to Drupal I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible.

This was one of the issues the gentleman asking this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167746/only-show-menu-level-2-from-active-trail-with-option-show-as-expanded) had.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanx